# How to create DialogBox in blackberry tabOS & how call next screen after click on button using Adobe flex4.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, blackberry

i am new to Blackberry application development.
now i am trying to make new app using adobe flex4.5 for Blackberry TabOS..
can anyone please guide How to create dialog box and how to call another screen by clicking on button????can anyone give sample code for the same...?

i am trying this code:

```
private function showLoginDialog():void
        {
            login = new LoginDialog();
            login.title = "Device is locked";
            login.message = "Please enter your username and password:";
            login.addButton("OK");
            login.addButton("Cancel");            
            login.passwordPrompt = "password";
            login.rememberMeLabel = 'Remember me';
            login.rememberMe = true;
            login.dialogSize= DialogSize.SIZE_SMALL;
            login.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,  dButtonClicked); 
            login.show(IowWindow.getAirWindow().group);

        }
```

it showing error as Access of undefined property dButtonClicked.& Access of undefined property group
-Access of undefined property IowWindow

can any one please help me to remove this error..?

Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the following documentation link:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Flex-for-the-BlackBerry-PlayBook-in-90-Minutes/ta-p/720803

Comment: @Vivek thanks i have edited my Q. can you please once go through it?

Comment: Are you test is code on the playbook simulator or actual device? Because IowWindow is only work on the simulator or device (not on the desktop).

Comment: @vivek okey...i have tested it on simulator..it giving error like above i have mention...Do u have any idea to remove?????

Comment: verify you have imported: import qnx.display.IowWindow; same above code work fine on my side.

Comment: @vivek hi..thanks alot...1 error removed..now it showing Access of undefined property dButtonClicked.....can you please tell me how can i remove?

Comment: dButtonClicked is the name of another function. Put simply null or create a function with name "dButtonClicked".