# What is "ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable qnx.display::IowWindow is not defined"?

Tags: actionscript-3, blackberry, flash-builder

I am trying to display dialog in Flex for Blackberry application.

I have tried following code but it gives me:

> ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable
>   qnx.display::IowWindow is not defined

this error at line number 8 i getting stuck with that.

So help me or give another way to display dialog in Flex

1. var myDialog:AlertDialog = new AlertDialog();
2. myDialog.title = "Dialog";
3. myDialog.message = "This is a small alert dialog";
4. myDialog.addButton("OK");
5. myDialog.addButton("Cancel");
6. myDialog.dialogSize = DialogSize.SIZE_SMALL;
7. myDialog.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, alertButtonClicked);
8. myDialog.show(IowWindow.getAirWindow().id);

Answer (score 1):

Find this thread and read the comment also.

[How to create DialogBox in blackberry tabOS & how call next screen after click on button using Adobe flex4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501759/how-to-create-dialogbox-in-blackberry-tabos-how-call-next-screen-after-click-on/6501863#6501863)

IowWindow class is only available on the playbook simulator or real device (not on the desktop).

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have not declared the variable IowWindow. YOu first have to declare it with `var` and then initialize it somewhere.

```
var IowWindow = new SomeWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually QNX-components aren't Flex-ready per se. You have to apply some hacks to use them in a Flex app: [Using qnx.ui.picker.Picker in mobile Flex Hero project for Blackberry Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271966/using-qnx-ui-picker-picker-in-mobile-flex-hero-project-for-blackberry-playbook)